# Data as relation between objects in Python

Tags: python, object, relation, datamodel

Chapter [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) in the section of *Language Reference* of *Python documentation* says:

> All data in a Python program is represented by objects or by relations
>   between objects.

I understand the part that all data in Python program is represented by **objects**. But what data is represented by **relations between objects**?

Can someone give an example with explanations, please?

Answer (score 2):

> But what data is represented by relations between objects?

For example, in

```
d = {2: 'b'}
```

the relationship is that the object 2 is mapped to the object `'b'` in the dictionary `d`.

In

```
l = [2, 'b']
```

the relationship is that the objects `2` and `b` are the 0 and 1 members of the list `l`.

In

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

f = Foo(2)
```

the relationship is that the object `2` is the member `_x` of `f`.